# Render Razor from Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to render Razor from my Angular controller, but cannot seem to get it to work.

I tried this in the controller:

```
            $scope.ssqsection = '<div>@Html.Partial("_MyPartial")</div>';
```

And this in my Html:

```
                        <div ng-bind-html="ssqsection | trustedhtml"></div>
```

NOte:
"trustedhtml" is a filter:

```
app.filter('trustedhtml', function ($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
});
```

this filter works whenever I want to insert HTML, however with the Razor syntax, it merely displays as text.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.  Razor is a server side language, Angular views are rendered on the client.

Comment: Is there anyway to inject the Angular into the razor like @Html.Partial({{myscopevariable}}) I know that syntax is of course wrong but I though it would help to make sense of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, everything rendered using Razor will eventually end up at the client as HTML so yes, it can include Angular view syntax as well.  You cannot pass the actual variable value, if that's what you mean, because the value of myscopevariable is of course only available on the client, not the server.